# What is the best Ubuntu option for my laptop?

Tags: software-installation

What is the best Ubuntu flavour to install on a Acer Aspire 5100 laptop?

Comment: Additional info: Acer Aspire 5100 has 1,6 GHz, 1 GB RAM and 120 GB HDD. [source](https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-aspire-5100-5747-15-4-turion-64-x2-tl-50-vista-home-premium-1-gb-ram-120-gb-hdd-series/specs/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Linux I would suggest Ubuntu or Linux Mint as they offer the easiest installation and are very easy to use.

**EDIT:**

The specs for an Acer Aspire 5100: 1,6 GHz, 1 GB RAM and 120 GB HDD
A light-weight distro like XUbuntu or Lubuntu would work best on a system with these specifications.

Comment: ok but ubuntu have a lot of packeges

Comment: If you are looking for a light-weight distro try Lubuntu or XUbuntu. Both are much smaller than the normal Ubuntu variants, but offer the same services.

Comment: @KrisStadler I suggest you add this information to your answer, see the specs in my comment to the question.